# How to create the following function of polynomial?

Tags: r, function

I would like to create a function with an argument 'n' like the following:

(a_n)*x^n + (a_n-1)*x^(n-1) + ... + (a_1)*x+(a_0)

with (a_i)s coefficients known already.

I know it is a simple question but I just can't figure out how to do it.

My thought is to construct a vector of functions:

```
xx <- numeric(n+1)
  for (i in 1:n+1) {
    xx[i] <- function(x) x^i
  }
```

and with `coe` is the vector of coefficient I defined, I could try:

```
coe %*% xx
```

which gives me the answer. But this didn't work and R displayed the following error message:

```
Error in xx[i] <- function(x) { : 
  incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```

Hope there're some other simpler ways to do this!

Comment: Have you tried the stats function 'poly' to construct a polynomial?

Comment: @eyjo Nope. Could you explain in details how that works?

Comment: poly(x, degree=n, raw=TRUE) %*% coe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Function to calculate (a_n)*x^n + (a_n-1)*x^(n-1) + ... + (a_1)*x+(a_0)**

```
p <- function(x,coefs) {
ens <- rev(seq_len(length(coefs)))-1
sapply(x,FUN=function(x)sum(coefs*x^ens))
}
```

Example

```
> p(x=2,coefs=c(0.5,-3,1,-2))
[1] -8
> p(x=1:3,coefs=c(0.5,-3,1,-2))
[1]  -3.5  -8.0 -12.5
```

Comment: Still not familiar with basic vector algebra in R I guess...Neat solution, thanks!

Comment: @ElaineC I believe your approach could work. Try to have xx as result instead of function to get that result.